# Could Seabios be preventing keyboard input from getting to Ubuntu?

Tags: keyboard, 18.04

I've been doing some troubleshooting with my laptop keyboard, and I was wondering if it was possible that its input wasn't even getting to Ubuntu. So, to anyone who may know the answer, could Seabios be ignoring my keyboard?
I've edited the RW_LEGACY in my Chromebook to be Seabios instead of the regular BIOS. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just learned that my chromebook supports full ROM editing now, so I changed SeaBIOS from RW_LEGACY to Full ROM, and now it works perfectly!
I hope this helps someone in the future :)